# How to speed up my sequential port scanner using multi-threading & return successful values only?

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I was trying convert sequential code of port scanner to become fast as it's so slow :(.

**Sequential code**

```py
import sys ,socket
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread

def target():
    t=input(str("Enter  target:"))
    target=socket.gethostbyname(t)
    try:
        for p in range(1,1026):
            s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            result=s.connect_ex((target,p))
            if result==0:
                service=socket.getservbyport(p)
                print(f"port {p} is open service {service}")
            else:
                 print(f"port {p} is close")

            s.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit()
    except socket.error:
        print("Host not responding")

def main():
    target()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I successfully convert it Faster But I want to get successful output only in `ThreadPoolexecutor` but I can't here What I do.

**Fast Code**

```py
import socket
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import re


def scan(ip, port):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    scanner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    scanner.settimeout(.1)
    ip = re.sub("(https:// | http:// | \/)", '', ip)
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(ip)

    try:
        scanner.connect((ip, port))
        scanner.close()
        with lock:
            result = f"Port {port} is OPEN Running {socket.getservbyport(port)}"
            print(result)
            return result
    except:
        pass


def run(ip_num: str, scan_fn, nums_ports: int) -> list:
    result = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        for port in range(nums_ports):
            future = executor.submit(scan_fn, ip_num, port + 1)
            result.append(future.result())
    print(result)  # empty
    return result


def main():
    ip = input("target> ")
    run(ip, scan, 1025)
    # with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    #     for port in range(1025):
    #         executor.submit(scan, ip, port + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output if Target `google.com`

```bash
target> google.com
Port 80 is OPEN Running http
Port 443 is OPEN Running https
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Port 80 is OPEN Running http', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'Port 443 is OPEN Running https', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

this above Output comes out after a long time how to make it faster and just take the successful result of that printed in first.

Comment: The script runs fine on my computer (Win10, py3.10) and the `result` list is not empty, so the problem isn't reproducible.  By the way, you are not actually doing any multithreading here.  The call to future.result blocks until the result is available, so your `for port...` loop must wait for `scan_fn` to finish before making the next call to submit.  You never run more than one thread at a time.

Comment: I work on Linux so this is the problem?

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  I'm not aware of any significant difference between python threading on the two different platforms.  You're describing a situation where the line `future=executor.submit...` executes just fine, but the line right underneath it `results.append...` doesn't.  Are you sure that the program you are running is EXACTLY the same as one you posted?

Comment: thx you, you are right I update the ouput. but it's so long time to output>:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your program is slow is here:

```
def run(ip_num: str, scan_fn, nums_ports: int) -> list:
    result = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        for port in range(nums_ports):
            future = executor.submit(scan_fn, ip_num, port + 1)
            result.append(future.result()) # Waits for function to return a value
    print(result)
    return result
```

The call to `future.result()` doesn't return until the future is done.  Your main thread must wait until one of your secondary threads runs the function `scan_fn` (which is actually the function named `scan`).  The future isn't done until `scan` runs, finishes and returns a value.  Even though you are running in a Pool, the logic of your program forces the calls to `scan` to execute one at a time.  You get no benefit at all from multithreading.

There are a couple of ways to fix this.  You might consider using the capability of pool.map but here is a simple approach that is similar to your existing program, using `pool.submit`.  I made no changes to the function `scan`.  I hard-coded the url because I got tired typing "google.com" at the prompt :-)

```
import socket
import threading
import concurrent.futures
import re
import time


def scan(ip, port):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    scanner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    scanner.settimeout(.1)
    ip = re.sub("(https:// | http:// | \/)", '', ip)
    ip = socket.gethostbyname(ip)

    try:
        scanner.connect((ip, port))
        scanner.close()
        with lock:
            result = f"Port {port} is OPEN Running {socket.getservbyport(port)}"
            print(result)
            return result
    except:
        pass


def run(ip_num: str, scan_fn, nums_ports: int) -> list:
    futures = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        for port in range(nums_ports):
            futures.append(executor.submit(scan_fn, ip_num, port + 1))
        # At this point all the futures are pending, and are running
        # in 100 other threads
    result = []
    for future in futures:
        r = future.result()   # Wait on each result
        if r is not None:     # Save only the non-None results
            result.append(r)
    print(result) 
    return result


def main():
    t = time.time()
    run("google.com", scan, 1025)
    print("Total execution time", time.time() - t)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The program output is:

```
Port 80 is OPEN Running http
Port 443 is OPEN Running https
['Port 80 is OPEN Running http', 'Port 443 is OPEN Running https']
Total execution time 1.2854032516479492
```

The execution time for 1025 scans is only 1.28 seconds.

Comment: Thx man I'm sorry for being tired God bless you thx very very much for help and explanation.